# How to test if action is dispatched in NgRX?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a component which is dispatched actions in constructor:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {    
  constructor(store: Store<State>) {
    store.dispatch(action1());
    store.dispatch(action2());
  }
}
```

I need to test if action1 and action2 is dispatched. I'm trying to do it with MockStore:

```
import {MockStore, provideMockStore} from '@ngrx/store/testing';

let store: MockStore;

beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
      provideMockStore({ initialState }),
    ],
  }).compileComponents();
  store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
});
```

And here is my tests:

```
it('should dispatch an action1 in constructor', () => {
  TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

  const expected = cold('a', {a: action1()});

  expect(store.scannedActions$).toBeObservable(expected);
});

it('should dispatch an action2 in constructor', () => {
  TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

  const expected = cold('a', {a: action2()});

  expect(store.scannedActions$).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```

This is strange but only one test is passed. It depends on the order of the dispatch() calls.

store.scannedActions$ contains only one value. If component code is:

```
constructor(store: Store<State>) {
  store.dispatch(action1());
  store.dispatch(action2());
}
```

then store.scannedActions$ contains only `action2()`

if component code is:

```
constructor(store: Store<State>) {
  store.dispatch(action2());
  store.dispatch(action1());
}
```

then store.scannedActions$ contains only `action1()`

How to test both actions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems like `scannedActions$` even though it is plural (actions) only has the last Action dispatched stored looking at its [interface](https://ngrx.io/api/store/testing/MockStore).

I would just use `spyOn` and spy on `store.dispatch` and see if it was called with the right actions.

```
import {MockStore, provideMockStore} from '@ngrx/store/testing';

let store: MockStore;

beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
      provideMockStore({ initialState }),
    ],
  }).compileComponents();
  store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
});

it('should dispatch action1 and action 2 in constructor', () => {
  const dispatchSpy = spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough(); // spy on the store 
  // dispatch but still call the actual implementation
  TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges(); // used to call ngOnInit, maybe it is not needed

  expect(dispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(action1());
  expect(dispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(action2());
});
```